# Im running python and trying to do something with the mouse library but It says it isnt installed

Tags: python, mouse

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\evren\Desktop\cc.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mouse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mouse'
```

this is the error

```
import mouse
mouse.get_position
```

this is the code

I downloaded mouse to the folder using pip install mouse
when I ran the file it said that the mouse library wansn't installed. I searched it up online and downloaded manager and panda too. But still the issue hasnt been resolved. Can you help me?

Comment: Same  thing is happening with the keyboard and time libraries too